# Confusion on the computation of Leave One Out cross validation?

Tags: self-study, cross-validation

1) I was studying about `cross-validation` and have a bit of confusion here. I understand about the `k-fold` technique, where if you have 100 data and do `10 folds` validation, you use the `n=10` data for training and another `n=90` for calculating the error (or maybe the other way round?

However, when you do leave on out, you are basically training on `n=99` data, and calculating error on the `n=1` data? how do this work? because you can't basically fit on one data? Or am I getting something wrong here?

2) Secondly, isn't fitting data with a higher degree of polynomial always yield less error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check again how cross-validation works. But maybe start with a simple train-test split (hold-out estimation). To answer your Questions:

1) It's the other way around. And you do it k=10 times, so that each instance is used to train 9 models and is predicted exactly once.

No, you are training on 99 data and predicting the 1 data point in your validation set.

2) Yes, true for in-sample error. Maybe you are overfitting and your test error is much higher.

Comment: in that case does the higher test error = overfitting/underfitting? Is there's a way to check if it's under-fitted or overfitted?

Comment: low training error/high test error = overfitting, yes. You use your validation and test set to detect and "avoid/reduce" overfitting.